# Apache 2.2 - many READ state requests - but this is not slowloris attack

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6

I have problem with Apache and slow read request (see pic). This is not slowloris - we have mod_antiloris. On this server one from many domains have thousands request in minute (some mobile app check status). What can I set to better performance?

Many configs tried. This is current:

```
KeepAlive Off
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    15
MaxSpareServers  20
ServerLimit      50
MaxClients       50
MaxRequestsPerChild  50
ListenBackLog 65536
```

ˇ
sysctl -p

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
kernel.sysrq = 0
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 65536
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
kernel.msgmnb = 65536
kernel.msgmax = 65536
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
vm.swappiness = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1
```

[image: SLOW READ REQ]

**EDIT 1:**

This issue we have on all servers, but there are about 5 connections in READ. On this we have max connections in READ sometime.
Thank you.

**EDIT 2**

```
#0  0x00007f92aad5f098 in __poll (fds=0x7ffffd321a10, nfds=1, timeout=<value optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/poll.c:83
#1  0x00007f92ab259717 in apr_wait_for_io_or_timeout (f=<value optimized out>, s=<value optimized out>, for_read=1)
    at support/unix/waitio.c:51
#2  0x00007f92ab25501a in apr_socket_recv (sock=0x7f92b4e372f8, buf=0x7f92b4e69568 "itoposvem.cz", len=0x7ffffd321af0)
    at network_io/unix/sendrecv.c:87
#3  0x00007f92abc4b465 in socket_bucket_read (a=0x7f92b4e41be8, str=0x7ffffd321af8, len=0x7ffffd321af0, block=<value optimized out>)
    at buckets/apr_buckets_socket.c:36
#4  0x00007f92abc4a417 in apr_brigade_split_line (bbOut=0x7f92b4e68bf0, bbIn=0x7f92b4e37e20, block=APR_BLOCK_READ, maxbytes=8192)
    at buckets/apr_brigade.c:319
#5  0x00007f92ac7928a2 in ap_core_input_filter (f=0x7f92b4e37dc0, b=0x7f92b4e68bf0, mode=AP_MODE_GETLINE, block=APR_BLOCK_READ,
    readbytes=0) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/core_filters.c:155
#6  0x00007f92a64d8d09 in logio_in_filter (f=<value optimized out>, bb=0x7f92b4e68bf0, mode=<value optimized out>,
    block=<value optimized out>, readbytes=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/modules/loggers/mod_logio.c:125
#7  0x00007f92ac786e26 in ap_rgetline_core (s=0x7f92b4e675e8, n=8192, read=0x7ffffd321ce8, r=0x7f92b4e675b8, fold=0,
    bb=0x7f92b4e68bf0) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/protocol.c:231
#8  0x00007f92ac78788e in read_request_line (conn=0x7f92b4e374e8) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/protocol.c:596
#9  ap_read_request (conn=0x7f92b4e374e8) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/protocol.c:913
#10 0x00007f92ac79fa30 in ap_process_http_connection (c=0x7f92b4e374e8) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/modules/http/http_core.c:183
#11 0x00007f92ac79b7d8 in ap_run_process_connection (c=0x7f92b4e374e8) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/connection.c:43
#12 0x00007f92ac7a7ad7 in child_main (child_num_arg=<value optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:667
#13 0x00007f92ac7a7dea in make_child (s=0x7f92adb59860, slot=8) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:763
#14 0x00007f92ac7a8a6c in perform_idle_server_maintenance (_pconf=<value optimized out>, plog=<value optimized out>,
    s=<value optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:898
#15 ap_mpm_run (_pconf=<value optimized out>, plog=<value optimized out>, s=<value optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/mpm/prefork/prefork.c:1102
#16 0x00007f92ac77f9b0 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffffd3221c8) at /usr/src/debug/httpd-2.2.15/server/main.c:763
```

Comment: You really want keepalive off?

Comment: Is I wrote, it is one of many configurations what I tried. Because many request are from new IP and dont use K-Al. - because it is receive only plain text page... so I think that this is not ba idea. And intersting info about it is here https://servercheck.in/blog/3-small-tweaks-make-apache-fly

Comment: I would start by checking using various tools like top, vmstat and such, if there is a cpu or disk i/o bottleneck. Also if an apache child is really slow on serving the request, you can try to attach to one with strace and ltrace, to check what is he waiting for.

Comment: @Dan . thanks I add backtrace now, can you check it? i cant read it :)))